# C++: Checking whether a string character is a digit using isdigit. .

Tags: c++, string

I am reading input for my program in a loop using getline.

```
    string temp(STR_SIZE, ' ');
    string str_num(STR_SIZE, ' ');
    ...
    getline(cin, temp, '\n');
```

After which, I use a function to find the next delimiter(white space) and assign all the characters before the white space to str_num. Looks something like this:

```
    str_num.assign(temp, 0, next_white_space(0));
```

I have verified that this works well. The next step in my solution would be to convert str_num to an int(this part also works well), but I should check to make sure each character in str_num is a digit. Here's the best of what I've tried:

```
    if(!isdigit(str_num[0] - '0')) {
        cout << "Error: Not an appropriate value\n";
        break; /* Leave control structure */
    }
```

For some reason, This always prints the error message and exits the structure. 
Why is that?
I've used operator[] for string objects before, and it seemed to work well. But, here, it's totally messing me up.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try getting rid of the `- '0'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) takes a char's integer value and checks it.

So, remove the - '0' and just pass str_num[index] to isdigit().

Note: because this function comes from C, the old style of treating chars as integers shows through in the method taking an int.  However, chars can promote to int values, so a char becomes an int just fine and this works.

Comment: Thanks. I was using reference from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/) which shows the parameter as int c. Works great now.

Comment: Though, if I'd stopped to think, I would have noticed the resemblance to isalpha() and not made such a simple mistake.